# How to validate custom component that uses http request with Formik?

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

Could you give me an example how to display errors from custom component?

So far my code looks like:

```
<Formik<LoginFormProps>
    initialValues={loginInitialValues}
    onSubmit={() => {})}
    validateOnBlur={false}
    validateOnChange={false}
    validateOnMount={false}
    isInitialValid={false}
>
    <Form className={styles.loginForm}>
        <IdentityInput/>
    </Form>
</Formik>
```

I have more code in my files but they are pure guesses

The `IdentityInput` is a `Field` with `input` and `Button` that on click shots the http request to the server and gets error response back.

I cannot display this message within the `IdentityInput` component.

The custom component code:

```
interface IdentityInputProps {
    errors: string[]
}

export const IdentityInput = (props: IdentityInputProps) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

    const onChangeHandler = (changeEventHandler: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValue(changeEventHandler.target.value);
    };

    const canGoNext = value.length >= 3 && props.errors.length === 0;

    return (
        <Field name={"loginId"}>
            {({ field, form: {touched, errors}, meta, }: FieldProps<string, LoginFormProps>) => {
                return (
                <>
                    <div className={`${styles.formSection} ${styles.leftPadded}`}>
                        <input {...field} type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={value} autoFocus />
                        <button className={"btn-blue"} disabled={!canGoNext}>
                            Next
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    { errors.identity &&
                        <ErrorContainer errors={[errors.identity]}/>
                    }
                </>
            ); }}
        </Field>
    );
};
```

Comment: Could you show how the custom component works?

Comment: @Vencovsky I placed the code. I don't know if the custom component can contain the validation error itself, or it has to be passed by props from Formik (i feel it counterintuitive since the idea of that custom component is that it can evaluate itself without any dependencies).